# React: the data I insert is NULL in my DB

Tags: reactjs, async-await, google-geocoder

After filling in the form the memorialpage object gets made and added to the db. From my form I get my data and everything is good to go except for the address that is get. By using react-geocode I get the latitude and the longitude which I need, but the objects get made and posted before I can get the lat and lng so in the DB these are just NULL.

I know that my mistake is that I am not awaiting the geocoder but I have tried making it into a function but still no luck.

Thanks for your help!

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {

    if (image !== null) {
      await handleUpload();
    };
    
    //Transforming the address that we get to latitude and longitude
    Geocode.setApiKey("x");
    Geocode.setLanguage("nl");
    Geocode.setRegion("be");
    //Google geocoder returns more than one address for given lat/lng, according to google docs, ROOFTOP param returns most accurate result
    Geocode.setLocationType("ROOFTOP");
    Geocode.fromAddress(data.Adres).then(
      (response) => {
        const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
        console.log(lat, lng);
        setAdresLatitude(lat);
        setAdresLongitude(lng);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );

    //Object for memorialPage
    let memorialPage = {
      FirstName: dataMemorial.FirstName,
      LastName: dataMemorial.LastName,
      BirthDate: dataMemorial.BirthDate,
      DateOfDeath: dataMemorial.DateOfDeath,
      Obituary: null,
      Quote: data.Quote,
      QuoteAuthor: data.QuoteAuthor,
      IntroText: data.IntroText,
      Latitude: adresLatitude,
      Longitude: adresLongitude,
      IsUndertaker: null,
      Undertakers_Id: null,
    };

    await app.put(`/api/update-memorialpages/`, memorialPage, axiosConfig);

    //Post adminhasMemorialPage
    await app
      .post(`/post/admin-has-memorialpage/`, idChecker, axiosConfig)
      .then((res) =>
        history.push({
          pathname: "/memorialpage-form-3",
          state: memorialPage,
        })
      );
  };
```

Comment: Do you get `lat,lng` on console?

Comment: What do you mean by `making it a function` in last line? you should directly await the `Geocode.fromAddress` and take that into a response.

Comment: Yes, I get the correct data there. What I mean by making a function is that I tried making a function outside of the onSubmit and giving it data as a prop, and then calling the function in onSubmit like handleUpload and awaiting it.

Comment: Then I would suggest you to add a check if `lat,lng` are available before sending the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `await` for the `Geocode.fromAddress` response before populating the `memorialPage` object if you are using an `async` function.
Also, there is no need to use the `then` for the post call if you are using `await`.

Try to change your code like this:

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
  if (image !== null) {
    await handleUpload();
  }

  //Transforming the address that we get to latitude and longitude
  Geocode.setApiKey('x');
  Geocode.setLanguage('nl');
  Geocode.setRegion('be');
  //Google geocoder returns more than one address for given lat/lng, according to google docs, ROOFTOP param returns most accurate result
  Geocode.setLocationType('ROOFTOP');

  try {
    const response = await Geocode.fromAddress(data.Adres)
    const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
    setAdresLatitude(lat);
    setAdresLongitude(lng);

    //Object for memorialPage
    let memorialPage = {
        FirstName: dataMemorial.FirstName,
        LastName: dataMemorial.LastName,
        BirthDate: dataMemorial.BirthDate,
        DateOfDeath: dataMemorial.DateOfDeath,
        Obituary: null,
        Quote: data.Quote,
        QuoteAuthor: data.QuoteAuthor,
        IntroText: data.IntroText,
        Latitude: adresLatitude,
        Longitude: adresLongitude,
        IsUndertaker: null,
        Undertakers_Id: null,
    };

    await app.put(`/api/update-memorialpages/`, memorialPage, axiosConfig);

    //Post adminhasMemorialPage
    await app.post(`/post/admin-has-memorialpage/`, idChecker, axiosConfig)
    
    history.push({
        pathname: '/memorialpage-form-3',
        state: memorialPage,
    })
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
  }
};
```

Comment: So I used your code and first of all it looks way cleaner than my code, but it still didn't work. After doing some tests with the console.log I decided on changing the states (adresLatitude, setAdresLatitude) to just normal variables and it worked that way. I don't think I was using states wrong, but maybe my understanding of them is not correct. Thank you for the help!